# How should I place my math functions?

Tags: delphi

I must calculate the answer to this math problem:  (√trunc(25.7)) - (2.2)^2

My code gives me an error saying "Incompatible types". The problem lies within my sqrt function. If I remove sqrt my program works.

The error message that displays:
[Error] Unit1.pas(32): Incompatible types

My code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, Math;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnEnter: TButton;
    redOut: TRichEdit;
    procedure btnEnterClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnEnterClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: Real;

begin
  x := Sqrt(Trunc(25.7)) - Power(2.2,2);
  Writeln(FloatToStr(x));
end;

end.
```

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: There is no problem evident in your code. However, we do not know the context of the procedure, nor do we know what `redOut` is. Still, I'd guess `lines` is a `TStrings`, and then there should be no problem at all.

Comment: Nope, your edit is no good. That compiles fine too. I suggest you read my answer carefully.

Comment: This error message indicates that some unit you are pulling into your code using Uses is defining a procedure named Sqrt which conflicts with the one in Math.  Try holding down the control key and clicking on the Sqrt function to see if it locates the offending duplicate function.  Also try the more exact `Math.Sqrt` way of referencing.  I wonder if you or another user on that machine accidentally MODIFIED a system unit to add a Sqrt() function to a local VCL source code units. If they did, that damage to your machine could be undone by carefully restoring the original files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written the code compiles. For example, this complete program

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Math;

var
  x: Real;

begin
  x := Sqrt(Trunc(25.7)) - Power(2.2,2);
  Writeln(FloatToStr(x));
end.
```

compiles.

So, why does your code not compile? The only rational explanation is that you have another, competing, function names `Sqrt` or `Trunc` or `Power`. Find that other function and remove it.

As an example, the following program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Math;

var
  x: Real;

function Power(Base, Exponent: Cardinal): Cardinal;
begin
  Result := 1;
  while Exponent > 0 do begin
    Result := Result * Base;
    dec(Exponent);
  end;
end;

begin
  x := Sqrt(Trunc(25.7)) - Power(2.2,2);
  Writeln(FloatToStr(x));
end.
```

fails to compile with the following error:

> [dcc32 Error] E2010 Incompatible types: 'Cardinal' and 'Extended'

---

Some other advice:

1. Get into the habit of posting a complete program that illustrates your problem. The complete programs that appear in this answer are the sort of thing you are looking for. Make the shortest, simplest, but complete program that illustrates the problem. As an added benefit of doing this, you'll likely solve the problem yourself.
2. Always quote error messages verbatim. Error messages contain useful information. By transmitting partial error messages you deny us access to that information. In fact, once you realise that error messages contain information then you'll read them more carefully yourself, and be able to use the information to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I've been learning delphi for 3 days now. I'll follow your advice.